# Watch command -d=cumulative gives unexpected behavior with --color

Tags: linux, bash, date, colors, watch

This script gives the expected behavior, highlighting the parts of the date that change:

```
watch -d=cumulative date
```

[image]

However this script highlights the entirety of the text instead of just the things that change:

```
watch -d=cumulative --color date
```

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Only the developers of `watch` (which seems to come from the `procps` package) can give a definitive answer about whether their software is behaving as expected. You should file a bug report and see what they say. (For the record, I can reproduce what you've done here, and I agree it looks like a bug.)